# Pagination issue in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am applying pagination in ReactJS (15 records per page).
When the page loads, the first 15 records display properly on page 1, but when I go directly to page 3 or 4 or any higher page, it displays nothing. I have to go back to page 1 and then page 3 or 4 to load the records, or I can go step-by-step (like first go to page 1, then page 2, then page 3, and so on).

The request is sent to fetch the records when I click on page 4 and I do get the records as well but somehow it is not displaying it.

Something is wrong with the way I am using and setting the project variable in the useState hook but not sure what is going wrong.

The script that I am using to retrieve the records from the database is shown below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProject = async () => {
    try {
      const { data: projectData, error: projectError } = await supabase
        .from("Projects")
        .select("*")
        .eq("id", projectId)
        .single();

      const {
        data: drawingsData,
        error: drawingsError,
        count,
      } = await supabase
        .from("Drawings")
        .select(`*`, { count: "exact" })
        .eq("project_id", projectId)
        .order("id", { ascending: true })
        .range(
          (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
          (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage + recordsPerPage - 1
        );
      setCount(count);

      setProject((prevProject) => {
        if (!prevProject) {
          return { ...projectData, drawings: drawingsData };
        }

        return {
          ...prevProject,
          ...projectData,
          drawings: [...prevProject.drawings, ...drawingsData],
        };
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  fetchProject();
}, [projectId, currentPage, recordsPerPage]);
```

Here is the pagination code.

```
const indexOfLastRecord = currentPage * recordsPerPage;
const indexOfFirstRecord = indexOfLastRecord - recordsPerPage;
const currentRecords = project?.drawings && project?.drawings?.slice(
  indexOfFirstRecord,
  indexOfLastRecord
);
const paginate = (pageNumber: number) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
const pageNumbers = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(count / recordsPerPage); i++) {
  pageNumbers.push(i);
}
```

I am using the `currentRecords` variable for rendering the list of records.

Here is the pagination code.

```
<ul className="pagination">
    <li className={`page-item previous ${currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
        <a href="#" className="page-link" onClick={() => paginate(currentPage - 1)}>
            <i className="previous"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    {[...Array(Math.ceil(count / recordsPerPage)).keys()].map((number) => (
        <li key={number + 1} className={`page-item ${currentPage === number + 1 ? 'active' : ''}`}>
            <a href="#" className="page-link" onClick={() => paginate(number + 1)}>
                {number + 1}
            </a>
        </li>
    ))}
    <li className={`page-item next ${currentPage === Math.ceil(count / recordsPerPage) ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
        <a href="#" className="page-link" onClick={() => paginate(currentPage + 1)}>
            <i className="next"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>;
```

I am calling the pagination code after I render the records onto the screen.

Comment: What are you using `currentRecords` variable for? Are you using that to render? Also, where are you calling the `paginate` function, can you share the code?

Comment: @PiyushSatija Yes, I am using `currentRecords` to render the records and I have also updated the question